# responsive datatables not working when we select data in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello please help me guys to solve the problem i am facing. so here i want to insert data into datatables but using class and id because there is select function in it and in html i made an error but why error huh? it should be when we click on the data in the dropdown it will automatically appear in the table and the data will be automatically responsive`
'Use Strict';

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblLvl2Process').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "ordering": true,
        "paging": true,
        "info": true,
        "bfilter": true,
        "scrollx": false,
    });
});

$("#selectMainProcess").change(function () {
    var mainid = $(this).val();
    var docid = $("#BPM_BPMDocNo").val();
    var fusid = "" + mainid + "$" + docid + "";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/BPM/GetBPMCoreProcessList",
        data: { sIdentifier: fusid },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#selectCoreProcess").empty();
            $("#selectLevel2Process").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#selectCoreProcess").append("<option value ='" + row.CoreProcessCode + "'>" + row.CoreProcessText + "</ option>")
            });
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            $(".allcorelist").hide();
            $(".alllv2list").hide();
        }
    });
});

$("#selectCoreProcess").change(function () {
    //hidden all row
    $(".allcorelist").hide();
    $(".alllv2list").hide();
    //get core process id
    var coreid = $(this).val();
    var series = 1;
    //dropdown level 2 type
    var aListVal = [];
    var aListText = [];
    $("." + coreid + "").each(function () {
        var codelv2 = $(this).find("#tdLevel2ProcessCode").text();
        var textlv2 = $(this).find("#tdLevel2ProcessText").text();
        aListVal.push(codelv2);
        aListText.push(textlv2);
    });
    $("#selectLevel2Process").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < aListVal.length; i++) {
        if (aListText[i] != "DELETE") {
            $("#selectLevel2Process").append("<option value ='" + aListVal[i] + "'>" + aListText[i] + "</ option>")
        }
    }
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    //show selected
    $("." + coreid + "").show();
    //numbering
    $.each($("." + coreid + ""), function () {
        $(this).find(".num").html("" + series + "");
        series = series + 1;
    });
});

$("#selectLevel2Process").change(function () {
    //hidden all row
    $(".alllv2list").hide();
    //get core process id
    var lv2proid = $(this).val();
    var series = 1;
    //show selected
    $("." + lv2proid + "").show();
    //numbering
    $.each($("." + lv2proid + ""), function () {
        $(this).find(".num").html("" + series + "");
        series = series + 1;
    });
});

$("#btnSubmitNewLvl2P").click(function () {
    var result;
    result = $("#frmLv2P").valid();

    if (result) {
        var row;

        $('a[href$="EDIT_Lv2P"]').off('click');
        $('a[href$="DELETE_Lv2P"]').off('click');

        if (sStateGridLvl2P == "-") {
            var row = $('<tr id="' + $("#txtCode").val() + '" class="' + $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val() + ' allcorelist" >' +
                            '<td></td>' +
                            '<td class="num"></td>' +
                            '<td id="tdLevel2ProcessText">' + $("#txtLevel2Process").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdLevel2ProcessDesc" style="white-space:pre-wrap">' + $("#txtDescription").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdLevel2ProcessObj" style="white-space:pre-wrap">' + $("#txtObjective").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdOtherEntity">' + $("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdMainProcessCode" hidden>' + $("#txtMainProcessCode").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdMainCoreProcessCode" hidden>' + $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td id="tdLevel2ProcessCode" hidden>' + $("#txtCode").val() + '</td>' +
                            '<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="#?id=EDIT_Lv2P" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" Title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;<a href="#?id=DELETE_Lv2P" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" Title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>' +
                '</tr>');

            $("#tblLvl2Process tbody").append(row);
     
        } else {
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[1].innerHTML = $("#txtLevel2Process").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[2].innerHTML = $("#txtDescription").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[3].innerHTML = $("#txtObjective").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[4].innerHTML = $("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[5].innerHTML = $("#txtMainProcessCode").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[6].innerHTML = $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val();
            $("#tblLvl2Process").children().children()[sStateGridLvl2P].children[7].innerHTML = $("#txtCode").val();
            $("#tblStoreOtherEntityLv2P tbody").find("#" + $("#txtCode").val() + "").find("#tdOtherEntity").text($("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val());
            $.each($("." + $("#txtCode").val() + ""), function () {
                var paramIME = $("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val();
                if (paramIME == "YES") {
                    $(this).find("#tdOtherEntity").html($("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val());
                }
            });
        }

        $('a[href$="EDIT_Lv2P"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            GoEditLv2P($(this));
        });

        $('a[href$="DELETE_Lv2P"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisvar = $(this);
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'CONFIRMATION',
                message: 'Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data ini ?',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
                closable: true, // <-- Default value is false
                draggable: true, // <-- Default value is false
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'YES',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function (dialogItself) {
                        GoRemoveLv2P(thisvar);
                        dialogItself.close();
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'NO',
                    cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                    action: function (dialogItself) {
                        dialogItself.close();
                    }
                }]
            });
        });

        var series = 1;
        $.each($("." + $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val() + ""), function () {
            $(this).find(".num").html("" + series + "");
            series = series + 1;
        });

        $("#tblLvl2Process").trigger('footable_collapse_all').trigger('footable_redraw');
        $("#ModalLevel2Process").modal('hide');

        //change dropdown level 2 process
        var coreid = $("#selectCoreProcess").val();
        var aListVal = [];
        var aListText = [];
        $("." + coreid + "").each(function () {
            var codelv2 = $(this).find("#tdLevel2ProcessCode").text();
            var textlv2 = $(this).find("#tdLevel2ProcessText").text();
            aListVal.push(codelv2);
            aListText.push(textlv2);
        });
        $("#selectLevel2Process").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < aListVal.length; i++) {
            if (aListText[i] != "DELETE") {
                $("#selectLevel2Process").append("<option value ='" + aListVal[i] + "'>" + aListText[i] + "</ option>")
            }
        }
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

        sStateGridLvl2P = "-";
        $("#txtLevel2Process").val("");
        $("#txtDescription").val("");
        $("#txtObjective").val("");
        $("#txtMainProcessCode").val("");
        $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val("");
        $("#txtCode").val("");
        $("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val("");
        $("#ModalLevel2Process").modal('hide');

    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Standard Template 2020</title>
    <!-- favicon -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body class="fixed-sn kalbe-skin">
    <!-- Page Wrapper -->

    <div class="preloader">
        <div class="loading">
            <img src="~/Image/1200px-Kalbe_Farma.svg.gif" width="200">
               <p class="text-center pt-4 ml-4" style="font-size : 15px; font-weight : 500;">
                    Loading...
                </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary shadow-lg sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar" style="margin: 0px; ">
        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->
        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">
                <header>
                    <!-- Topbar -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                        <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->

                        <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class=" d-md-none rounded-circle border-0 mr-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
                        <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                            <button class="border-0 toggel-nav" id="sidebarToggle">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-flex-icons ml-auto" id="NavbarTop">
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- End of Topbar -->
                </header>
                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid box">
                    <!--Main Layout-->
                    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                           <div class="shadow-sm tbl-1 p-3 mb-5" style="background : #F1F1F1;">
    <div class="text-left text-table">
        <h3 class="ml-2 mt-2" id="labelHeader">List Operational Risk</h3>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="p-2">
                <div class="form-group selct-kalbe" id="searchEntity">
                    <div class="" id="labelEntity">
                        <label for="selectSearchEntity">ENTITY</label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="selectSearchEntity" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" data-width="100%">
                        @foreach (var item in ListEntity)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 mt-4 pt-3 portfolio-item" id="labelDocNo" hidden>
                <div class="form-group" style="float:right">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectSearchDocNo">Doc No: </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 mt-4 pt-3 portfolio-item" id="searchDocNo" hidden>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="selectSearchDocNo" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 mt-4 pt-3">
                <button type="submit" id="btnReload" class="btn btn-sm btn-kalbe"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left : -7px;">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <input placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-sm" style="border-radius : 20px" type="text" id="ListOPR" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="searchFilter row pt-3" style="margin-left : -7px;">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group" id="selectSearchEntity">
                    <div class="" id="">
                        <label for="selectSearchEntity">TABLE FILTER</label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="mdb-select colorful-select dropdown-primary md-form" multiple id="searchFilterSelect" style="border-radius : 20px" data-size="10" data-width="100%" onchange="filterColumnOnChange()">
                        <option value="DocNo">Doc. No.</option>
                        <option value="RefDoc">Ref. Doc. No</option>
                        <option value="Entity">Entity</option>
                        <option value="Process">Process</option>
                        <option value="LastUpdate">Last Update</option>
                        <option value="LastRevisit">Last Revisit Status</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSelectAll" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="SelectAll()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;SELECT</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnRemove" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="RemoveFilter()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;REMOVE ALL</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row mt-4 ml-1">
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="PICProcessInput" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right rounded-pill" title="PIC Process Input">0/0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="SuperiorPICProcessInput" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="Superior PIC Process Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="PICRMReview" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="PIC RM Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="PICSBUReview" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="PIC SBU Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row mt-4 ml-1">
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="PICRADevReview" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="PIC RA Dev Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="HeadEntityReview" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="Head Entity Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <button id="Approved" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-arrow-right" title="Review">0/0</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" id="btnExportLMRModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right:10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export List Mandatory Risk</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-right: 37px;">
                <button type="button" id="btnExportLRAA" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right:20px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export List Risk Above Tolerance</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" id="btnExportURR" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right:10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Updated Risk Register</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" id="btnExportLOR" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right:0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export List Operational Risk</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" id="btnExportLKR" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="margin-right:10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export List Key Risk</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="button" id="btnNewOR" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm divbtnNew" style="margin-right:10px; display:none"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;New Operational Risk</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Loading");}
    <div class="card card-custom">
        <!-- Editable table -->
        <div class="card ">
            <div class="card-body">
                <!-- Collapse buttons -->
                <!-- / Collapse buttons -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-12">
                        <div id="divTblListOR" class="table-responsive" style="overflow: hidden;">
                            <table id="tblListOR" class="table table-striped table-condensed text-left display responsive nowrap text-left" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="theadCollapse">Collapse</th>
                                        <th>No</th>
                                        <th class="theadDocNo">Doc. No.</th>
                                        <th class="theadRefDoc">Ref. Doc. No</th>
                                        <th class="theadEntity">Entity</th>
                                        <th class="theadProcess">Process</th>
                                        <th class="theadLastUpdate">Last Update</th>
                                        <th class="theadLastRevisit">Last Revisit Status</th>
                                        @*
                                            <th>Supporting Document</th>*@
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Editable table -->
    </div>
</div>


                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <!--Main Layout-->
                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer page-footer">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <a>&copy; 2020 - Standard Template 2020 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are methods for DataTable() that take care of what you want to do. Note that I have changed the IDs for the new table row TD elements into classnames - because you shouldn’t duplicate id’s.  Rather than do inline styles, set up a new classname `prewrap`

```
<style>
.prewrap{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

Somewhere at the top of your script, get a reference for the DT

```
const t = $('#tblLvl2Process').DataTable();
```

and in your loop:

```
// to replace your TR insert in your loop -- insert the data
t.row.add( [
"",
"",
$("#txtLevel2Process").val(),
$("#txtDescription").val(),
$("#txtObjective").val(),
$("#txtOtherEntityLv2P").val(),
$("#txtMainProcessCode").val(),
$("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val(),
$("#txtCode").val(),
'<a href="#?id=EDIT_Lv2P" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" Title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;<a href="#?id=DELETE_Lv2P" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" Title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>'
        ] ).node();

// add id and class to the tr
t.id = $("#txtCode").val();
t.addClass(' + $("#txtMainCoreProcessCode").val() + ' allcorelist')

// now the tds
 $(t).find('td').eq(1).addClass('num');
 $(t).find('td').eq(2).addClass('tdLevel2ProcessText');
 $(t).find('td').eq(3).addClass('tdLevel2ProcessDesc prewrap');
 $(t).find('td').eq(4).addClass('tdLevel2ProcessObj prewrap');
 $(t).find('td').eq(5).addClass('tdOtherEntity');
 $(t).find('td').eq(6).addClass('tdMainProcessCode');
 $(t).find('td').eq(7).addClass('tdMainCoreProcessCode');
 $(t).find('td').eq(8).addClass('tdLevel2ProcessCode');

t.draw( false );
```

I can't test this, but that should take care of it.